# issue with linking c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I have a bit of an issue in static linking. I have a static library (libkells.lib) which is made up of a header file containing function declarations and a .cpp file containing the function implementations. I successfully compiled the two into an .o file and then built the static library out of them.

Then I have a file mcmd.cpp which calls the functions in the .lib file. I have included the header file involved in the static library into this mcmd.cpp file. This file (mcmd.cpp) successfully compiles into an .o file but when I try to build it into an executable file, my compiler returns a message like this:

> libkells.lib(libkells.o): In function ZNKSt13move_iteratorIPSsE4baseEv
>   . Undefined reference to __cxa_end_catch, Undefined reference to
>   __cxa_begin_catch

and so many other errors. When I look keenly at these error messages, these errors seem to originate from some header file called `include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h`. I'm using mingw 4.7.1 on Windows. What is it that I'm not doing right?

Comment: Not enough information, show us the command line for compiling and linking your code, please.

Comment: All cpp files? don't need the `c` tag.

Comment: What's the exact link command that you're using?

Comment: For linking, are you using `ld` directly or using `g++ -o` ?

Comment: I'm using Quincy 2005 ide. so ive specified the directory of the .lib file and the linking options necessary. the ide seems to use gcc to compile the stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not linking against libstdc++ or not using g++, in short the 'gcc' driver, being the C driver, not the C++ driver, doesn't link the C++ runtime at the end. If you want, you can explicitly add -lstdc++ to the command line, or, definitely the first choice in general, just use 'g++'

Comment: cool, so what do I type on the command line (as in the parameters) using g++

Comment: muchas graçias dude! g++ worked! so I should use g++ on c++ and gcc on c